# Mediaelement | flash player | How to remove youtube player branding

Tags: mediaelement.js

I just want to remove youtube branding on right bottom corner of video player. I tried various ways available on net but don’t get success.
e.g(?modestbranding=1).

Answer (score 0):

You can add ?modestbranding=1 to your url. That will remove the logo.

modestbranding (supported players: AS3, HTML5)

This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.

&showinfo=0 will remove the title bar.

showinfo (supported players: AS3, AS2, HTML5)

Values: 0 or 1. The parameter's default value is 1. If you set the parameter value to 0, then the player will not display information like the video title and uploader before the video starts playing.

add  "?modestbranding=1" to each instance of the YouTube player URL for the old embed code -> like this:

```
<object width="560" height="349">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: do you add it to each instance of the YouTube player URL for the old embed code -> like this:                              <object width="560" height="349">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="349" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>

Comment: My Code is like this:<video width="1004" height="460" controls="control" id="Nx-video-player" autoplay="true" data-txt-play="Play" data-txt-stop="Stop" data-video-name="NEXXUS HERO VIDEO">            
            <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/t8gfgvSizAM?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" />            
        </video>